# What beast/creature is this from "Avengers: Endgame"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

During the final battle in *Avengers: Endgame*,

> Thanos has several types of monsters fighting on his side. The known ones were definitely the **Chitauri** and **Leviathans** from ***The Avengers (2012)*** and the **Outriders** from ***Avengers: Infinity War (2018)***.

Additionally, there were some kind of

> giant Gorilla/ape kind of beast (*image below*).
>
> [image: The giant gorilla/ape creature]
>   <sub>*the image isn't very clear*</sub>

What creature is this? Does it have a specific name (*like the ones given to the Chitauri, Outriders etc.*)?

Comment: MCU wikia lists them as "Chitauri giant dogs".. However that's hardly a reliable source of information.......

Comment: They brought a cave troll...

Comment: Every evil overlord worth his salt should have a cave troll.

Comment: You might consider accepting an answer to this. It seems to be properly answered now even if you didn't believe it was before.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to an interview with WETA Digital Visual Effects Supervisor Matt Aitken, these creatures are called "Chitauri gorillas".

> In a new interview with SlashFilm, WETA Digital Visual Effects
>   Supervisor Matt Aitken discussed the battle and revealed who was on
>   Thanos' side. Aitken confirmed that the fight featured three groups of
>   alien warriors who appeared in previous Marvel Cinematic Universe
>   movies.
>
> Aitken revealed that this massive battle introduced the Chitauri
>   gorillas.
>
> "We see the Chitauri leading them out by chains and then they set them
>   free," Aitekn said. "These are not quite King Kong sized, but yeah,
>   giant gorilla-ish, alien gorilla creatures who are a formidable force
>   to be reckoned with on the battlefield."

[Source article](https://www.cbr.com/avengers-thanos-endgame-army/)

Answer (score 6):

#### Chitauri Gorilla

Whilst the [other answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/217426/58193) already covers this I just wanted to answer this with something a little bit more official. There is a page in *Marvel's Avengers: Endgame - The Art Of The Movie* which covers these new characters with a bit of concept art and they are indeed named Chitauri Gorilla.

> [image: Page from the book showing the Chitauri Gorilla, the text is in the centre of the page (quoted below) but there are three images above and three below: Above shows the Chitauri Gorilla in it's normal form, walking on its back legs and resting on its front arms from the back, front and side; the bottom shows it in a T-pose from the back and then two front shots with the middle looking to the side]
>
> Seen alongside the Chitauri army is a new beast: the Chitauri Gorilla. "They needed a big bad guy for the final battle in *Endgame*," Concept Artist Jerad Marantz says. "I imagined it as a big gorilla, or just maybe a berserker version of the Chitauri aliens that we see. Maybe they're genetically modified or mutated, but they move like gorillas, so I just thought that kind of movement on the battlefield would work for what they wanted to accomplish with those sequences."
>
> <sub>*Marvel's Avengers: Endgame - The Art Of The Movie*</sub>